# What results of the implementation in this array

Tags: c

What results of the implementation in this array?
Num_in_rankA [Arank] + +;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean

```
Num_in_rankA[Arank]++
```

without the spaces, it adds one to "Arank-th" element of the array called Num_in_rankA.